# Button BackgroundTint not working with AppCompat v23

Tags: java, android, button, android-appcompat

I'm trying to use AppCompat v23 so that I have full Button coloring using BackgroundTint.

I have added `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.+'` to my app's build.gradle file.

I have my app theme set with `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` in AndroidManifest.xml

In styles.xml I have:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

I'm not trying to override anything, I'm just trying to get the base theme to work.

I am using `public class LandingActivity extends AppCompatActivity` in my main activity declaration.

Finally, within the layout I have `android:backgroundTint` on a Button to set a color in colors.xml.

On a device running 5.0 the colors work perfectly.  On 4.0 devices there is no coloring on the buttons.  It's the default grey.

I'm sure that I'm missing something, but I have no idea what it is.  **Are there any other steps that I need to take to allow the AppCompat library to work its magic?**

Comment: Simply put, backgroundTint was added in API21 (5.0).

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.no/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html

The full list of tint aware widgets at this time is:
-AppCompatButton

Comment: I think it's a bug of this version .use version 21 instead 23 .I hope it will works

Comment: @Nathan that doesn't mean it reads attributes from the XML layout. It could never do read `android:backgroundTint` on 4.0, because it is not implemented. In the future (I don't think there's one now) we might be able to use `app:backgroundTint`, but not `android:`. What *tint aware* means is that it chooses its own color from the color attributes you set in styles. I don't remember which color determine the button background, but you can try with `colorControlNormal`, `colorAccent`, `colorPrimary` ...

Comment: @Nathan did some research and it looks like v23 release of appcompat introduced `app:backgroundTint` too. So change `android:backgroundTint` to `app:backgroundTint` (you'll be asked to import the namespace).

Comment: I already have the app namespace set up with xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Can you let me know what you're looking at as well?

Comment: So? `app:backgroundTint` doesn't work either?

Comment: Just [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/intl/en/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatButton.html), first few lines. I'm not sure it refers to API<21 though.

Comment: app:backgroundTint isn't found, so the linter throws namespacing errors.  The coloring works though.  The buttons have backgroundTint on multiple versions now.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of 
`<Button android:backgroundTint="~" />`,

try to use

`<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     app:backgroundTint="~"/>`